# Error parsing xmldsig-core/xmldsig-core-schema.xsd

Tags: java, xml, xsd, wsdl, cxf-codegen-plugin

I am generating the client code from a wsdl file. Without any change on code, it stopped working and now I'm getting the following error message:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
>   org.apache.cxf:cxf-codegen-plugin:2.1.2:wsdl2java (generate-sources)
>   on project myProject: org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLRuntimeException: Fail
>   to create wsdl definition from :
>   file:/C:/myproject/src/main/resources/myservice.wsdl [ERROR] Caused by
>   : WSDLException (at
>   /wsdl:definitions/wsdl:types/xsd:schema/xsd:schema):
>   faultCode=PARSER_ERROR: Problem parsing
>   'http://www.w3.org/TR/xmldsig-core/xmldsig-core-schema.xsd'.:
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException:
>   http://www.w3.org/TR/xmldsig-core/xmldsig-core-schema.xsd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copy the contents of the schema here

https://archive.evolveum.com/downloads/midpoint/1.9/midpoint-xsddocs-1.9/schemas/xmldsig-core-schema_xsd/schema-overview.html#xml_source

to a local file and amend  'http://www.w3.org/TR/xmldsig-core/xmldsig-core-schema.xsd' to the new path of your local schema.

or amend   'http://www.w3.org/TR/xmldsig-core/xmldsig-core-schema.xsd' to:
https://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-xmldsig-core-20080610/xmldsig-core-schema.xsd

This is happening because one of the references again references this link. By default wsdl2java will try to open all linked xsd's - if they are needed or not. Please also check -nexclude option for wsdl2java http://cxf.apache.org/docs/wsdl-to-java.html

Comment: But 'http://www.w3.org/TR/xmldsig-core/xmldsig-core-schema.xsd' is not included directly in my file. It's being included somehow

Comment: it might be referenced in one of the references, you might want to post your wsdl by editing your question

Comment: Yes it's being referenced by the references. Should I amend them all? btw, why is this happening?

Comment: I mean, why this link disappeared?

Comment: can't tell that, sorry. i assume it is by mistake, it is a pretty old document...